# PayPal Invoicing. SandBox. How to "pay" the invoice?

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm building Invoicing system.
My client wants to send PayPal invoices without loggin to PayPal account.

I managed to make CreateInvoice() and CreateAndSendInvoice() functions to work (thanks to @Andrew Angell again!!!).

But now I need to "pay" the order. How do I act as a buyer, and pay the invoice?

There was no actually email sent to my box. I do see related record in 'notifications': "You've received an invoice XXX from YYY". But how, how do I "pay" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you login to http://sandbox.paypal.com using the email address of the account that you sent the invoice to you'll see the invoice in the history just like a regular receiver would.  You can pay it directly from there.

Comment: How I didn't think about it myself? :):):)